# fullPage.js jQuery plugin into Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-plugins, fullpage.js

I need help.
I would like to use the great fullPage.js jQuery plugin by Alvaro Trigo (http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/) in the front-page of the 'Responsive' Wordpress theme by CyberChimps (http://wordpress.org/themes/responsive).
I am not sure exactly what to do and I would need a step by step explanation.
Many thanks for your time and your huge help.

Comment: Do you want to know how to include fullPage.js in WordPress? Or do you want to know how to work with fullPage.js?

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't make a lot of sense for me. Fullpage.js is a full screen layout. You don't need a responsive wordpress theme for it.

Comment: In case you still interested. Check out [this wordpress theme](https://goo.gl/HuFudq) using fullpage.js.